# noexcept specifier mysteriously breaks compilation (clang, gcc disagree)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, noexcept

The code in question is

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template <typename F>
void for_each(F&&) noexcept {}

template <typename F, typename T, typename... Us>
void for_each(F&& f, T&& v, Us&&... us) {
  std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<T>(v));
  for_each(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Us>(us)...);
}

void func(void*) noexcept {}

int main() {
  for_each(func, nullptr);
}
```

It compiles on [gcc 8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kWMYa4q1zkkYOJlR), but fails on [clang 6](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BBNBHck5NFIrvLGx) with the following error:

```
/opt/wandbox/clang-6.0.0/include/c++/v1/type_traits:4198:19: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to a function type
    static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) > 0, "Type must be complete.");
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/wandbox/clang-6.0.0/include/c++/v1/type_traits:4203:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__check_complete<void (void *) noexcept>' requested here
    : private __check_complete<_Tp>
              ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-6.0.0/include/c++/v1/type_traits:4496:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__check_complete<void (&)(void *) noexcept>' requested here
    : private __check_complete<_Fp>
              ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-6.0.0/include/c++/v1/type_traits:4559:9: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__invokable_r<void, void (&)(void *) noexcept, nullptr_t &&>' requested here
        __invokable<_Fp, _Args...>::value,
        ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-6.0.0/include/c++/v1/type_traits:4568:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__invoke_of<void (&)(void *) noexcept, nullptr_t &&>' requested here
    : public __invoke_of<_Fp, _Args...>
             ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-6.0.0/include/c++/v1/type_traits:4573:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::result_of<void (&(nullptr_t &&))(void *) noexcept>' requested here
template <class _Tp> using result_of_t = typename result_of<_Tp>::type;
                     ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-6.0.0/include/c++/v1/functional:2349:1: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'result_of_t' requested here
result_of_t<_Fn&&(_Args&&...)>
^
prog.cc:9:3: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'invoke' [with _Fn = void (&)(void *) noexcept, _Args = <nullptr_t>]
  std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<T>(v));
  ^
prog.cc:16:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'for_each<void (&)(void *) noexcept, nullptr_t>' requested here
  for_each(func, nullptr);
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Remove the `noexcept` specifier on `func()`

```
void func(void*) /* noexcept */ {}
```

It then compiles. I don't get this. Is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well no. libc++ fails to handle `noexcept` marked functions. It looks like its machinery fails for some reason when the function is `noexcept` and it takes the wrong partial specialization (the one for objects not for functions).

As you cannot take the `sizeof` of a function, clang rightly complains (and gcc would too).

As a workaround, pass in a function pointer:

```
for_each(&func, nullptr);
```

I filled a [bug report](https://llvm.org/pr37407), which was fixed! :)

Comment: Indeed. libc++'s `<type_traits>` has specializations of `__check_complete` for all sorts of function types, but misses the `noexcept`. This might be worth reporting to the bug tracker...

Comment: @Lingxi The bug has been fixed!! Thanks Eric